# C# ParseExact TimeSpan not recognized

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a simple string of arrayData that i'm trying to run a TimeSpan.ParseExact and i'm getting invalid format errors.  For the life of me I can't figure out what i'm going wrong and it's driving me nuts

```
string arrayData = "00:02:02.4000000";
string[] formats = new string[] {
  @"s\.f",
  @"ss\.f",
  @"ss\.ff",
  @"m\:ss\.f",
  @"m\:ss\.ff",
  @"mm\:ss\.ff",
  @"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff",
  @"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss"
};

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

TimeSpan _timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(arrayData, formats, culture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying culture.DateTimeFormat?

Comment: Don't the format strings require % signs (%m, %h, etc)?

Comment: Use "c" ,,,,,,,,,, as a format specifier, Timespan has different Format String than dates

Comment: @adelphus No, they don't. [The custom `TimeSpan` format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allow specifying `%` to disambiguate, but they don't require it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ParseExact`, you need to specify the exact format. In your case, you need to allow for seven fractional second digits, not just two.

```
string arrayData = "00:02:02.4000000";
string[] formats = new string[] { 
    @"s\.f",
    @"ss\.f",
    @"ss\.ff",
    /* ... */ 
    @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fffffff"   // <- missing format
};
TimeSpan _timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(arrayData, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```